# how to loop to view all images from the sqlite database

Tags: android

i am new to android and i have created a database using sqlite with images.When i view all my data i have inserted into the database only the hotness(string row) shows all the records but the images only show the first row.Can anyone help me please,l am desperate now.

```
public String getHot() {
             // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String[] columns = new String[] { KEY_HOTNESS };
            Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null,null,null);

    String hotness = "";
    int iRow = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_HOTNESS);
    for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {
        hotness = hotness + c.getString(iRow) + "\n";
    }
    return hotness;
}

public byte[] getImage1(int id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String[] columns = new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_HOTNESS,
    KEY_IMAGE1, KEY_IMAGE2, KEY_IMAGE3, KEY_IMAGE4,KEY_IMAGE5 };

    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null,
            null, null);
    if (c == null) {
        return null;
    }
    byte[] iMage1 = null;
    for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {
        iMage1 = c.getBlob(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(KEY_IMAGE1));
    }
    return iMage1;
}
```

Comment: i have tried adding the  "+ "\n" " in front of the iMage1 line but it gives me an error.So how do i make it go to the next record?thnx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is your solution: but it 'll also give you `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError:  bitmap` if your image size is large.

```
public ArrayList<Bitmap> getImage1(int id) { 
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ArrayList<Bitmap> a = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
        Bitmap bmp;

        String[] columns = new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_HOTNESS,
                KEY_IMAGE1, KEY_IMAGE2, KEY_IMAGE3, KEY_IMAGE4, KEY_IMAGE5 };

        Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null,
                null, null);
        if (c != null) {
            do {
                iMage1 = c.getBlob(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(KEY_IMAGE1));
                bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(iMage1, 0,
                        iMage1.length);
                a.add(bmp);
                iMage1 = c.getBlob(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(KEY_IMAGE2));
                bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(iMage1, 0,
                        iMage1.length);
                a.add(bmp);
                iMage1 = c.getBlob(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(KEY_IMAGE3));
                bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(iMage1, 0,
                        iMage1.length);
                a.add(bmp);
                iMage1 = c.getBlob(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(KEY_IMAGE4));
                bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(iMage1, 0,
                        iMage1.length);
                a.add(bmp);
                iMage1 = c.getBlob(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(KEY_IMAGE5));
                bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(iMage1, 0,
                        iMage1.length);
                a.add(bmp);

            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }

        return a;
    }
```